# Sequencing bind with pure functions

Tags: haskell

I often find myself wanting to insert regular functions into a "binded" sequence. Like in this contrived example:

```
getLine >>= lift (map toUpper) >>= putStrLn
```

I need to define the lift function `lift :: (a -> b) -> a -> m b` to make this work. Problem is I don't know of such a function, and [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Monad+m+%3D%3E+%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+m+b) doesn't seem to either. I find this odd since this makes totally sense to me.

Now, there are probably other ways to make this work, but I like the way point-free style code allows me to scan the line in one pass to figure out what is happening.

```
let lift f x = return (f x) in
getLine >>= lift (map toUpper) >>= putStrLn
```

My question boils down to this: am I missing something or how come there isn't a function like lift. My experience in Haskell is still very limited, so I am assuming that most people solve this in a different way. Can someone explain to me the idiomatic way of solving this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are three idiomatic ways.

1. Don't use bind; use the first hit on your Hoogle search instead:

   ```
   liftM (map toUpper) getLine >>= putStrLn
   ```

   There are a variety of alternative spellings of `liftM`, such as `fmap` or `(<$>)`.
2. Inline the `lift` function you defined:

   ```
   getLine >>= return . map toUpper >>= putStrLn
   ```
3. Use the monad laws to fuse the last two binds in option 2:

   ```
   getLine >>= putStrLn . map toUpper
   ```

Comment: I would put `foo >>= return . bar >>= baz` last in the list. It's fine in longer chains, but in short cases like the example, `foo >>= baz . bar` is much more readable IMO.

Comment: Actually I think `foo >>= return . bar >>= baz` is a neat way. It didn't occur to me that that actually _is_ the lift function I was looking for.

Comment: `putStrLn . map toUpper =<< getLine` looks pretty neat. I like to use `=<<` since it resembles function application.

Comment: @MagnusKronqvist indeed, you could define `lift = (return .)`, although option #3 (or similar, using `=<<` as danr suggests) is much preferred. Also, it's best not to use the name `lift` which is used by `MonadTrans`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Functor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Functor.html#t%3aFunctor) instance in such cases:

```
> import Data.Char
> import Data.Functor
> map toUpper <$> getLine >>= putStrLn
foo
FOO
>
```